# elixir - get item by index in nested amp

Tags: elixir

I have a structure like this:

```
map =  %{"a" => "foo",
         "b" => [%{"b1" => "bar",
                   "b2" => "baz"}]}
```

Simply what I'm trying to get is:

```
map.b[0].b1
```

what is the easiest way to get it?
is there a way to do it using `kernerl.get_in/2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using combination of [`Kernel.get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2) and [`Access.at/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#at/1):

```
map =  %{"a" => "foo",
         "b" => [%{"b1" => "bar",
                   "b2" => "baz"}]}

get_in(map, ["b", Access.at(0), "b1"])

# => "bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get an error because the keys of your map is strings, not atoms, and there's no `list[index]` syntax.

You can get it by

```
map["b"] |> Enum.at(0) |> Map.get("b1")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `List.pop_at` 

`map =  %{"a" => "foo", "b" => [%{"b1" => "bar", "b2" => "baz"}]}
map["b"] |> List.pop_at(0) |> (fn({res, rest}) -> res end).()`